# display barcode to jlabel java

Tags: java, user-interface, barcode

I have used the library from  [here](http://www.barcoderesource.com/javabarcode.shtml)  and I followed the steps to display barcode on jlabel.

code:

```
public Barcode(){
     initComponents();
     Code39 code39 = new Code39();
     String outputStr = code39.encode("123456789",1);
     jLabel1.setText(outputStr);
     jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("CCode39_S3", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 24));
}
```

Where its the same code but the problem when run program the jlabel display this : *1234567892*.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: any errors?....

Comment: There are no errors you can check through this site i do the same but iam get text result not barcode drawing

Comment: somehow font is not working.are you sure you follow all the steps?according to the document i think you should install the software

Comment: yes i following the same steps

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean about install software ?

Comment: in the documentation it says nevigate progamefiles/connectcode..... .did you do that step?how can there is a such a folder if we dont install a software.may be CCode39_S3 doesn't exist in your system.

Comment: Yes it is meant I must add .jar lib and import it .. without this step there will be an error ,, and i have do it

Comment: may be CCode39_S3 doesn't exist in your system << so how fix it ?

Comment: install the sfotware http://www.barcoderesource.com/download.html

Comment: if u have any other library it can do my function .. please tell me about it

Comment: that would change the question into asking for a tool or library, which is off topic. Your best bet for something that doesn't require the installation of anything separate from your software on the computer this is going to be used at is to generate the barcode as an image and place that on the GUI.